# jquery selector doesnt accept pipe character |?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an html ID I'm trying to call. It has a specific name build like this `name_|_anyting`
but when I try to get the elemetn using Jquery's selectors I get an error

```
$("#name_|_anyting")
```

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: |_anyting

so my question is : 
Are pipe characters not allowed as Ids in jquery selectors ?

Comment: Related: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: Pipe is not a valid character in an ID, so it's not valid in the jQuery selector for it either.

Answer (score 14):

`|` is a special character in selector syntax, which means you can't use it directly in an ID selector. If you cannot change the ID in your markup to accommodate your selector, you'll have to make do with escaping the selector to trick jQuery into selecting the element anyway:

```
$("#name_\\|_anything")
```

Answer (score 6):

Pipe character "|" has to be escaped using double backslashes.

> ### Selectors
>
> Borrowing from CSS 1–3, and then adding its own, jQuery offers a powerful set of tools for matching a set of elements in a document.
>
> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as **!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{**|**}**~**** ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \\. For example, if you have an element with id="foo.bar", you can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar"). The W3C CSS specification contains the complete set of rules regarding valid CSS selectors. Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on CSS character escape sequences for identifiers.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Your answer mentions double backslashes (\\), but your example only has a single backslash: `#foo\.bar`...

Comment: @cale_b His double backslash got eaten by StackOverflow. He just copied/pasted the description from the jQuery selectors page.

Answer (score 1):

To update an old question... In jQuery 3.0 you can now use [$.escapeSelector(selector)](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/). Examples:

```
$('#' + $.escapeSelector('crazy|id.selector') + 'Wrapper').show();
$('.' + $.escapeSelector(divClassVariable)).each(function() {...})
```

and (from the docs)

```
$( "div" ).find( "." + $.escapeSelector( ".box" ) );
```