# Unrecognised expression with error for ids starting with an integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to grab an element from a page which has an id starting with an integer.

```
$('#3|assets_main|ast_module|start-iso-date')
```

I get the following error

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: |assets_main|ast_module|start-iso-date

I am using jQuery 1.7.1, I understand that the id in general is poorly named but is there any reason why jQuery will has issues with ids that start with integers?

Comment: IDs are supposed to start with a letter. What you have is basically invalid. The error is to be expected.

Comment: Also, yeah, I just realised - are the `|` also part of the ID? Because those would also be invalid.

Comment: @vlaz not true in HTML5. Ids can contain any character at any position except spaces.

Comment: @vlaz yes I understand that it is poorly named, but I do not have the luxury of refactoring the code.

Comment: @vlaz HTML5 allows anything but spaces https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute and HTML4 only disallowed special characters not digits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery selector doesnt accept pipe character |?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306252/jquery-selector-doesnt-accept-pipe-character)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML5 the `id` can start with a numerical value, so your id is valid.

The issue is the pipe (`|`) characters in the selector; you need to escape them using `\\`:

```
$('#3\\|assets_main\\|ast_module\\|start-iso-date')
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/rbqaLd72/)

Comment: I thought, this may have been the case, so I tried the same but it did not fix my problem.

Comment: Are you sure? Because it works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/rbqaLd72/

Comment: It does not throw an error but it also can't find the element on the page

Comment: Have you ensured the element exists when you call this line of code? As you can see from the example, there's no reason this wouldn't work if the id values match