# Jquery Selector For This Type of Id?

Tags: jquery

I have an id like this

```
<input type="text" id=MyField[1d81c42a-4c8f-45a8-a219-0ff29d328103].Name />
```

I need to do this as otherwise some Asp.net mvc code won't work correctly when I submit and it tries to bind it to a model.

I am trying to now do a jquery selector on it but the element is never found

```
$('#MyField[1d81c42a-4c8f-45a8-a219-0ff29d328103].Name)
```

I think the brackets are messing it up.

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery escapeSelector() function?
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/

Answer from a while back to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306252/jquery-selector-doesnt-accept-pipe-character/47166905#47166905

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is that your HTML input element id is not double-quoted your HTML input like this

`<input type="text" id=MyField[1d81c42a-4c8f-45a8-a219-0ff29d328103].Name />` but it must be like this `<input type="text" id="MyField[1d81c42a-4c8f-45a8-a219-0ff29d328103].Name" />`

and in the jquery selector you forgot to add end quote `$('#MyField[1d81c42a-4c8f-45a8-a219-0ff29d328103].Name')`,

jquery id must be string always, so when you use special characters  certain characters must be escaped with backslashes`\\` from jQuery Id documentation  [here is link](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

and here is a working demo hope it will helpful for you.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
       var value = $('#MyField\\[1d81c42a-4c8f-45a8-a219-0ff29d328103\\]\\.Name').val();
       alert(value);
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="MyField[1d81c42a-4c8f-45a8-a219-0ff29d328103].Name" />
    <button>Get Value</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```